# Android Studio 1.1.0 hangs while editing build.gradle

Tags: android-studio, freeze

My machine has 8 GB of RAM. I installed Android Studio 1.1.0 and applied everything they posted [here.](http://geek.moneylover.me/android-studio-eliminate-shutter-n-lag/)

Everything works fine with a small Hello world app. But when I start editing `build.gradle` of a big project which we had moved from Eclipse, the IDE hangs for 20 or 30 seconds. It hangs even if I don't add or remove any lines. Even if I just press Enter. Besides I don't see any processes running (indexing, syncing, etc) at the bottom.

I checked `File -> Settings -> Gradle`, and `Use auto-import` was unchecked.

As they suggested, I ran `jstack -l <pid> > dump.txt` and posted a message along with `dump.txt` on https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=82706#c35

I can't attach the same `dump.txt` here because it contains about 800 lines.

Answer (score 3):

After some time looking into this issue, I found that it is an active issue among the Android Issue Tracker forum.

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars%20Reporter%20Opened&groupby=&sort=&id=59965

You'll see my comment in that thread but I'll post it here as well

> I did find out WHY my build.grade would hang upon touching (any amount
>   of editing once so ever).
>
> I had a statement where I would iterate over all the variants and
>   would then iterate over each variant's outputs and do a filter among
>   an xml file. Commenting the filter portion out would remove the
>   hanging/freezing problem. In fact only iterating over the first output
>   (of the first variant) would drastically reduce this lag time, still,
>   very annoying.
>
> I would suggest starting your build.gradle file from scratch and
>   adding parts progressively until you come across the portion in which
>   hangs the editing process.
>
> EITHER WAY, this hang shouldn't happen since I'm merely editing the
>   file, not compiling nor running.
>
> Hopefully this can help someone

Answer (score 1):

In your gradle.properties files uncomment the 3rd line below, if not exist create one yourself

```
# The setting is particularly useful for tweaking memory settings.
# Default value: -Xmx10248m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m
# org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
```

This help me a lot in android-studio performance

Comment: This answer seem to not match the question, but it's really worked for me.Thank you!